# Size of sample data to conduct FFFT in JTransforms

Tags: fft

I am working on get frequency of the audio data on a phone. I am using Jtransforms to conduct the FFT on sample data to get the result. But I am not sure how to set the sample data array size.

1. The hardware sample rate is 44100. My understanding is I can only get the frequency lower than 44100/2
2. How should I set the FFT_Size, bufferSize in the code below, if I want to get the full range of frequency result 0~44100/2.
3. When I get the result from realForward. How can I interpret the result into frequency magnitude inside a certain range(e.g. 5khz)?

   ```
   recorder.read(audioData,0,bufferSize);
   DoubleFFT_1D fft = new DoubleFFT_1D(FFT_Size);
   fft.realForward(audioData);
   ```

Thank you very much for you time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a particular sampling rate R, the results of an FFT can be thought of as a histogram of energy present in different frequency bands, ranging from -R/2 to R/2 Hz. So, for a 44100 Hz sampling rate, your frequency histogram ranges from -22050 Hz to 22050 Hz. The number of samples you input to the FFT is the number of bins that are output. So, if you input 1024 samples, you will have 1024 histogram bins between -22050 Hz and 22050 Hz, or 44100/1024 (about 430) Hz per bin. If you want resolution of 5000 Hz, you really only need about 9 samples.

Converting from the (real, imaginary) complex number format to (frequency, magnitude) is the same as converting from rectangular (complex) to polar (freq/mag) coordinates.